# How I send email after upload the CSV file into mysql database using spring boot and mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

After upload, show number of successful, number of failed records. Eg 49 successful, 1 fail.
After upload the csv file how to send the email with attachment csv file and success message.
After upload, create email trigger showing details of upload.

Dear Sir,
After upload, show number of successful, number of failed records. Eg 49 successful, 1 fail(through the REST APIs)
After upload the csv file how to send the email with attachment csv file and success message(through the REST APIs).
After upload, create email trigger showing details of upload(Through the REST APIs).

Comment: Please take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour. This platform requires a minimum effort from your side with a better explanation. Also please note that this is not a free code-writing community. I don't want to vote to close this but you need to help us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.